# GUI Extension - Unable to populate item using minor version

Tags: 2011, gui-extensions

**How to populate an item using minor version?** 
Am using the below code snippet.

var item = $models.getItem('tcm:222-7244-64-v1'); - **Works fine.**

var item = $models.getItem('tcm:222-7244-64-v1.3'); - **Throws error.**

I was able to get the minor version from DAL using below query as neither the CoreService nor Anguilla Framework provides it, but i need to populate the item using minor version. Could someone help me to resolve it?

select max(version)||'.'|| max(revision) as rev from items where item_reference_id='7244'

Comment: If all you need it the latest version, trying using -v0

Comment: Am working in workflow, so has the minor version. I tried using v0, but it returns only the major version. But i need to retrieve the metadata value of minor version of an item which is in workflow. Is there any way to get the minor version even using Coreservice? I can impersonate the same.

Comment: With Core service you should be able to get the current version _if_ you are impersonating the user that has the item checked out. Just add -v0 to the URI. PS - I'll test it later to make sure I know what I'm talking about :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use -v0 to get the latest version (which is the major and minor version). You can only do that if you are the current lock owner of the item; since the item is in workflow, that means you need to be the current assignee of the started workflow activity -- and you need to be editing the item (have loaded it with open mode = ViewOrEdit / EditWithFallback / Edit).

While you can request other specific versions (i.e. -v1) that only works for past, checked-in versions (=major versions).

Answer (score 4):

Thanks Nuno for saving my day. I was able to get the minor version data using 'v0' through coreservice from which am passing it to the js file. Please find below the code snippet.

```
Client client = new Client();
string tcmid = "tcm:222-7316-64";
IdentifiableObjectData identifiableObjectData = client.Read(tcmid, null);
if (identifiableObjectData == null) return;
FullVersionInfo fullVersionInfo = identifiableObjectData.VersionInfo as FullVersionInfo;
if (!fullVersionInfo.LockType.Value.HasFlag(LockType.NewItem))
{
    client.Impersonate("NT AUTHORITY\\SYSTEM");
    identifiableObjectData = client.Read(tcmid + "-v0", null);
}
```